# Density Optimization by Fitting an Circle to a Field - Monte Carlo Method

Tags: optimization

**Given:** I have 2D non-parametric formula that provides instantaneous intensity at certain (x,y) location.

**Required:** I want to en-circle a region where the density is high via optimization. In other words fitting a circle whose radius must be optimized such that the density is maximum at certain region.

**Analogy:** Consider an oil spill in water (assume stationary). I want to find an area enclosed inside a circle that constitutes highest density. It is to identify most important spots that require cleaning fast. So less dense area is not cleaned first.

The density can be computed by performing monte-carlo integration of the intensity values inside the a circle (size of which has to be optimized) and then dividing by the area of the circle. So if the size of circle grows so is its area. The outcome of optimization is the value of the radius of the circle and its position.

**Question:** Now considering the area is huge, and the problem cannot be solved analytically, what are some of the approaches/heuristics that I can use to solve the problem?

Comment: If the analogy to an oil spill is taken fairly literally (e.g. there is a source from which these intensity values have flowed and you now have a snapshot of these values), it may be help to find a maximum of the intensity first as the origin of your circle. From there, you could incrementally increase the radius until the density stops increasing.

Comment: You seem to be missing a "trade-off" variable, either in your objective function or constraints. By making the circle radius infinitesimally small, centered at the point of highest intensity, you get highest density, but little total capture.

Comment: @Tyberius this is exactly what I thought initially, I could simply "anchor" the center by solving this $$\textrm{argmax}I(x,y)$$ then, then once the circled is anchored at certain (x,y) simply solve for $$\textrm{max}\frac{\Sigma I(x,y)}{\pi \|x,y\|} $$ and get the maximum density. The problem with this is that if there are instantaneous peaks in the intensity value that gradually decreases then it wont work or compared to something that is possibly not peaky at all but consistant in intensity.

Comment: @gfdsal Thanks, the revised question is much clearer. I'll delete my comments, and if you want, you can delete your replies too.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone I absolutely agree with you, I can surely add an inequality constraint that area of the circle must be greater then some value to remove that pathological situation. But the main concern is how to solve this and if any convergence criteria exists.

Comment: Do you really want to locate a circle of some fixed radius, such that the integrated density is maximized? To optimize a trade-off,  you could jointly optimize center and radius of circle, by maximizing integrated density minus a cost, where the cost might be proportional to radius squared (or whatever suits your fancy). And what do you mean by non-parametric 'formula"? Given a point (x,y), what is involved in evaluating the density there?

Comment: @MarkL.Stone By non-parametric i mean a black-box function whose evaluation is expensive. So this blackbox will output you intensity values if you give it some (x,y) input but it doesnt have analytical form such as $x^3+x^2-y^4$ or something, so integration is out of the question. Your first point. No, I dont want to locate a circle with fix radius but instead optimize radius as well as its position that the density is maximum (with an additional constraint which you suggested for tradeoff).

Comment: You sdould provide more details on the black box evaluation. Are the evaluations "error-free"? Or are they random samples, with possible option to improve error statistics with greater evaluation time? Etc. Are you really doing density estimation (a large field in and of itself) as a 'function evaluation" step?

Comment: @MarkL.Stone good catch. I wanted to keep it simple as not to confuse anyone with potentially good strategy. The black box evaluation is gaussian process (GP) with mean and variance so not error free. I know how to deal with error part so I kept it simple deterministic function. The density is already estimated with GP, I just want to find the region with maximum density of "error metric" that takes into account both mean and variance. So the region where "error metric" not actual density is high -hereby presented as intensity - I want to circle that region by performing optimization.

Comment: Why not just optimize based on the GP mean function?  What form is that in? And what would be expensive about its evaluation? Or can you only generate samples from the GP and don't know its mean function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108243/discussion-between-gfdsal-and-mark-l-stone).